# C++ WMI - Fetch local IP address

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm trying to fetch the local IP via `WMI ManagementObject` but I get only empty/null strings.

With a call from `PowerShell`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

I get 13 elements 2 of which with a valid IP address.

But with the following code, passing
`"Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"` as *hardwareClass* and
`"IPAddress"` as *propertyName*:

```
void propertyValueLocal(String^ hardwareClass, String^ propertyName)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher^ searcher = gcnew ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM " + hardwareClass);
    ManagementObjectCollection^ collection = searcher->Get();

    for each (ManagementObject^ object in collection)
    {
        if (object[propertyName] != nullptr)
            Console::WriteLine(object[propertyName]);
    }
}
```

I get:

> System.String[]
>   System.String[]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have are two string arrays. Console.WriteLine is simply calling the ToString() method which is returning the name of the class. You need to look inside the string arrays.

Comment: Why does it work for other classes/properties like `Win32_VideoController`/`PNPDeviceID` then?